# is there any way i can replace the text in this pattern #abcd# to #{abcd} in notepad ++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Im trying to replace the this pattern #abcd# to #{abcd} in notepad++, is there anyway i can make use of search and replace option in notepad++ for this

Comment: If you are asking for a regex, you may need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Find: #(.*?)#

Replace with: #{\1}

Comment: what if there are multiple values like this?

Comment: hit the replace all button? You need to be more specific.

Comment: and suppose if i have continuous values like this #abcd#, #efgh#, its selecting the two values straightly. But i want each of those values selected separately

Comment: use #(.*?)# in the find box, the ? make it match the shortest string which satisfies the expression

Comment: Thanks a lot! working fine :D

Answer (score 0):

In Find box type: `#(abcd)#`
In Replace type: `#{\1}`

`\1` represents the first capture group as it is . in your case it is `(abcd)` excluding ()

you can replace abcd with any search string you like.